# Math formulation for # of outcomes of 2 indistinguishable dice

Tags: probability

I'm not sure why the equation for finding this is $(6 * 6)/{2!} + 6/3$ I understand that out of the 36 outcomes when they are distinguishable, we need to divide them by 2 to get rid of duplicates like (1,2) and (2, 1). But why are we adding $6/3$ back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the division, you divided the number of doubles by $2$.  Another way to look at it is of the $6^2$ possible rolls, possible rolls, $6$ are doubles. So we we have $$\frac{6^2-6}{2}$$ non-double outcomes, plus the $6$ doubles, which gives the same result.

Comment: That equals 15, not 21..

Comment: Oh did you mean $6^2 + 6$ on the numerator?

Comment: Wait I read that wrong, my bad, I thought the equation you wrote was for the whole problem